# How to serialize/deserialize an ASP.NET JSON date using Jackson?

Tags: java, asp.net, json, jackson

I'm having some difficulty trying to get Jackson to serialize/deserialize JSON date strings sent from an ASP.NET service.  The string is in the following format:

```
/Date(1234567890123)/
```

A simple example of the type of output I get from the server is like the following:

```
{
    "name" : "Bob Marley",
    "birthdate" : "/Date(1234567890123)/"
}
```

How can I get Jackson to convert the date to a Java date object?  Is there a way to do it without having to write a custom serializer/deserializer?

Comment: What do you want to do instead of writing a custom deserializer? It is not that much work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184477/gson-throws-exception-parsing-empty-date-field/9185368#9185368 You could alter the resulting object, deserialize as `String` and write a getter that parses the String at access. I don't think that is more elegant.

Comment: If anyone needs code, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906981/parsing-asp-net-mvc-returned-date-using-jackson-json-library-in-java. Although eventually I've switched to faster JSON library on the server that also gives you ISO8601 format - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973286/asp-net-mvc-json-datetime-serialization-conversion-to-utc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to write a custom deserializer. Or alternatively, to store the string representation of the date in your bean, but provide an alternative getter that converts the string to a date using a DateFormat instance. The first option is cleaner and more efficient.

[See question previously asked here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152076/deserializing-date-in-jackson).

Answer (score 1):

I think the ASP.NET service is producing a strange value for the date and would change that if I could. If I cannot, then writing a customer deserializer is the way to go.